# How to list questions for which I have left a comment

Tags: support, comments, inbox

There is a notification area (small red dot) that lists questions on which a user has made a recent remark. Once you click outside of it, it disappears.  Is it possible to get a full list (in last item first) order?

Comment: Are you looking for the 'Inbox' available from the 'StackExchange' dropdown?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10827/maesumi?tab=responses&sort=comments / http://stackexchange.com/users/1174715/maesumi?tab=inbox

Comment: that's it! thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to add `@JohnDoe` when you're responding to a comment (unless you're responding to the post owner, as I am right now; post owners are always notified).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your "inbox" for tex.sx at https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10827/maesumi?tab=responses&sort=comments (everybody can just see it for themselves). In order to get there manually, go to your profile, "responses", and "comments".

There's also a global inbox, showing comments from all Stack Exchange sites that you're a member of: http://stackexchange.com/users/1174715/maesumi?tab=inbox. Manual way: Go to your profile, "network profile", "inbox".

As for the terminology: Since the recent notification system revamp, the *inbox* (red circle) tells you when another user wrote something for you (comment, answer, chat message), the *notifications* (gray circle) are reserved for badges, which are considered less important.